In Tanstack table when a row is editable, how to get formik props dirty,errors,values of all the fields of that row
this is sample one field. When it turns editable goes to another component where this field turned into   {
header: 'GUI App Name ',
accessorKey: 'guiappname',
dataType: 'text',
validation: yup.object().shape({
guiappname: yup
.string()
.matches(/^[A-Za-z]+$/, 'Only alphabetic characters are allowed')
.required('This field is required')
})
},
return (
    <TableFW
      id="expanded-gui-profile-details-table"
      title={`${guiProfileName}'s Application List`}
      columns={columns}
      data={tableLoading ? [] : tableDatas}
      striped={false}
      filename={`${guiProfileName}'s Application`}
      enableSorting={true}
      enableMultiSort={true}
      pageIndex={0}
      pageSize={5}
      pageList={[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100]}
      enableRowSelection={true}
      enableMultiRowSelection={true}
      enableHiding={true}
      stickyHeader={false}
      stickyFooter={false}
      enableGlobalFilter
      hasExportPDF={operationNames?.includes('PDF')}
      hasExportCSV={operationNames?.includes('Excel')}
      refreshedOn={refreshedDateTime}
      refreshMethod={getGuiAppDetails.refresh}
      isRowEditable={true}
      updateOperation={editGuiAppOprinProfile}
      ExpandComponentProps={operations}
      //onFieldChange={handleFieldChange}
    />
 

);
}
